# command not found... error (Fedora 29)

Tags: fedora, gcc

I am following a tutorial on lex and yacc that requires me to compile some C source code.  The tutorial asks me to enter the following line into my terminal:

```
$ gcc ‑o exampleA lex.yy.c ‑lfl
```

But I then get the message:

```
bash: $: command not found...
```

I tried with a simpler HelloWorld C source code file and I get the same message.

But I know that the gcc executable is in /usr/bin and when I type 'gcc --version' or 'gcc --help' into the terminal I get a sensible response.

What is going on here?

BTW I am using Fedora 29 linux distribution.

Comment: SORRY - the answer is staring me in the face.  The copied and pasted code contains a $ sign at the beginning which was not my intention.  That teaches me for pasting stuff from the internet without checking it carefully first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including the dollar sign ($) when pasting the command. The error message indicates that bash can't find a command called `$`. You should only paste from `gcc` and forward.

Answer (score 0):

### *$=user #=root*

For some actions you need a root promission.

You can use sudo to get into root from a user profile. Do that by place a *sudo* infront of your action or access the sudo cell with *sudo -i*.

If that doesn't solve it, you should

1. update the database with *sudo dnf upgrade --refresh*
2. install *gcc* when *gcc* isn't pre installed at feora